# Modal window is not poping up

Tags: html, button, modal-dialog, click

A modal window has to popup when you click on Event button, but it is not in my example i have two buttons Event and Open Modal, when i click on open modal a window will get opened when i click on Event some other action will be happened this is absolutly fine. but I need only one button Event , if i add `id="myBtn` into the Event Button then it doesn't open the window but the callEvent() will be fine. how to perform both via same button click?

```
<div>
<button type="button" class="confirm"
style="color: blue;"
(click)="callEvent()">
Event
</button>
<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<button id="myBtn">Open Modal</button>
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

    <!-- Modal content -->
    <div class="modal-content">
        <span class="closes">&times;</span>
        <p>Some text in the Modal..</p>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

ts

```
  let modal = document.getElementById("myModal");
        let btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");
        let span: HTMLElement = document.getElementsByClassName("closes")[0] as HTMLElement;
      callEven(){
    //assigning event coad....
      ..
        btn.onclick = function() {
            modal.style.display = "block";
        }
        span.onclick = function() {
            modal.style.display = "none";
        }
        window.onclick = function(event) {
            if (event.target == modal) {
                modal.style.display = "none";
            }
        }
}
```